# Hows the Exceptional object is converted in to one of Java checked Exception?

Tags: java, exception

When we have a custom Exception, say `SkillRequiredException`, we check for some condition like checking the skill of the employee and if the condition fails we will throw `SkillRequiredException`.
Till this I am fine and clear.

But lets take `FileInputStream` class. It throws `FileNotFound` checked exception. When I see `FileInputStream` source code, I could not see anywhere - checking for some condition (and) `throw FileNotFoundException`.

My question is, how JVM knows that file is not present and how the Exceptional Object created by JVM is identified as `FileNotFoundException` with out using `throw FileNotFoundException` in `FileInputStream` class?

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you check which methods are called by the constructor of `FileInputStream`, you'll see that it eventually calls :

```
private native void open(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;
```

This is a native method, which means it's not written in Java and you can't see its code, but it can still throw a `FileNotFoundException` exception.

Comment: I could understand now Eran. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In FileInputStream you could find this code:

```
public FileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
      ...
      open(name);
}
```

and open is defined:

```
/*
 * Opens the specified file for reading.
 * @param name the name of the file
 */
private native void open(String name) throws FileNotFoundException;
```

You could easily check how your jdk uses jni to perform this operations depending on your os, for example for Windows using OpenJdk you could find this piece of code inside io_util_md.c ([complete source](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk7/jdk/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c)):

```
if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    int error = GetLastError();
    if (error == ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES) {
        JNU_ThrowByName(env, JNU_JAVAIOPKG "IOException",
                        "Too many open files");
        return -1;
    }
    throwFileNotFoundException(env, path);
    return -1;
}
```

And you could check the implementation of throwFileNotFoundException in io_util.c ([complete code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk7/jdk/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c)):

```
void
throwFileNotFoundException(JNIEnv *env, jstring path)
{
    char buf[256];
    jint n;
    jobject x;
    jstring why = NULL;

    n = JVM_GetLastErrorString(buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (n > 0) {
        why = JNU_NewStringPlatform(env, buf);
    }
    x = JNU_NewObjectByName(env,
                            "java/io/FileNotFoundException",
                            "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                            path, why);
    if (x != NULL) {
        (*env)->Throw(env, x);
    }
}
```